# Copy table into two new tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have one ugly SQL Server 2014 table that contains books.  Each book can be written by multiple authors, so that a book can be repeated many times in the table, one row for each author. The ISBN field uniquely identifies the book.

The data looks something like this:

```
TABLE NAME = "OldUglyTable"
ID     ISBN       BookTitle            AuthorName
1      1          My Awesome Book      John Smith
2      1          My Awesome Book      Sally Johnson
3      2          All About Cats       Frank Jones
4      1          My Awesome Book      A. Smithfield
```

What we have now done is created two new empty tables `Books` (with auto-incrementing `BookID`, `ISBN` (unique key), and `BookTitle`) and `BookAuthors`(with auto-incrementing `ID`, `BookID` (FK to `Books`), `AuthorName`). The original `ID` field is garbage and we don't really care about it.

I cannot change the table structures, but I am trying to quickly move the records into these two tables by creating one record per unique `ISBN` in the `Books` table, then creating a record for each author in the `BookAuthors` table that has a FK out to the new record just created in `Books` on the `BookID` field.

How can I split up this data into these two new tables efficiently and get the FK to insert into `BookAuthors` too?

I have over 60 million rows!  I tried doing a row number partition on ISBN and getting just the first row from a CTE since `DISTINCT` doesn't necessarily always return the correct data, but that even gave me

> 'System.OutOfMemoryExceptionSystem.OutOfMemoryException'

error in SSMS. :(  I'm not sure what the best way to proceed would be.

Comment: PS: I guess I can just spit out my test results and queries to a text file according to this article to avoid the System.OutOfMemoryException error.  My real issue is simply getting the right queries to move over the data and create the FK relationships.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874903

Comment: Can you post your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `INSERT` distinct books into the `Books` table using this query:

```
INSERT INTO Books(ISBN, BookTitle)
SELECT DISTINCT
    ISBN, BookTitle
FROM OldUglyTable
```

Then, `INSERT` author to `BookAuthor` using `INNER JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO BookAuthors(BookID, AuthorName)
SELECT
    b.BookID, t.AuthorName
FROM OldUglyTable t
INNER JOIN Books b
    ON b.ISBN = t.ISBN
```

To help improve the performance, I suggest you create these two index after the insert in the `Books` table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IXN_Books_ISBN ON Books(ISBN)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IXN_OldUglyTable_ISBN ON OldUglyTable(ISBN) INCLUDE(AuthorName)
```